# aspnetdb.mdf file is not getting created?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I have VS2012 and I'm creating a website application in ASP.NET using C#.
I want to use VS2012 built in membership and role tool to create users and roles.

Problem is that `ASPNETDB.mdf` database is not getting created in `App_Data` folder when I launch ASP.net configuration utlility. Moreover there is no refresh utility when I right click on my solution explorer?

My SQL Server 2008 and IIS are on another machine.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Either [create the database and tables yourself](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/membership/creating-the-membership-schema-in-sql-server-cs) - or use the `aspnet_regsql.exe` utility in your ASP.NET folder to create those objects for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either [create the database and tables yourself](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/membership/creating-the-membership-schema-in-sql-server-cs) using SQL scripts that Microsoft provides - or use the [`aspnet_regsql.exe` utility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862%28v=vs.140%29.aspx) in your ASP.NET folder to create those objects for you (in whichever database you choose to create them in).

Comment: Inside my app_data folder How can I create this schema.I am asking this from you since it is a bit tough I hope you could guide me here.

Comment: @khan: you'd have to create the `ASPNETDB` database on a server first, run the `aspnet_regsql` utility against it, and when that's done, detach the database from the server and copy the `.mdf` file to your `App_Data` folder - or better yet: **just leave it on the server!**

Comment: I have created the aspnetdb database on server and since VS2013 does not have website configuration tool by default for adding roles and users I used this link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/08/19/asp-net-web-configuration-tool-missing-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx.  So ASP.net configruation utility is running just fine.Now problem is that aspnet configuration or web site administration tool is not pointing to aspnetdb. that is when I added new users and roles and refreshed my aspnet database on sqlserver it was not updated.Can You help me here?

Comment: @khan: no sorry, I've never used the ASP.NET membership stuff much... put that into a new question and ask it ! I'm sure *someone* will be able to help you with this!